# Is Access 'select where' query performance affected by number of records

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

How much of an impact does the number of records in a table have on the performance of a query that returns approx 5k records using a 'date is greater than' criteria?

For example where a table might have a total of 50k records vs 100k.

Comment: Is there an index on the date field?

Comment: @SchmitzIT yes sorry should have mentioned that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes, more records to retrieve will take longer to load. However, it's impossible for us to give you a specific number, as there's a lot of factors involved, and every scenario would be different.

Specifically, it could depend on whether or not the database is hosted locally or on a server. It would depend on indexing, hardware (disks, specifically), possibly network speed, etc., etc.

If you're pulling twice as much data, theoretically it should take about double the time, but again, YMMV. With proper indexing, it might be faster.

Incidentally, if speed (and perhaps more importantly, recovery, security, storage size and multi-user usage) might be an issue, you're probably better off switching to SQL Server.